# Azure cosmos db bulk import

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Is bulk import available for Azure cosmos db(Mongo db API)?
I want to import large dataset set which is available in a json file to Azure cosmos for Mongo DB.
I tried importing using mongoimport and Java mongo APIs but it took a long time and timed out in the end.

Any suggestions on how to import it directly from my file to cosmos db?

PS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-java --- says bulk executor is not available for cosmos's mongo db yet.

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Thanks for your response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bulk executor library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-java) is not available for cosmos db Mongo Api:

[image]

Cosmos db migration tool is not available for cosmos db Mongo Api as well:

[image]

As workaround,please get an idea of Azure Data Factory [Copy Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) which supports transfer data from a file into [cosmos db Mongo api sink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db-mongodb-api). The source file could be from [Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage) or [File System on-premise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system) even.

Answer (score 0):

First create a empty database in cosmos DB with AUTOSCALE mode and set the throughput to some high value depending upon the size of your DB.
Then use mongorestore, this should do