# Azure cosmos db gremline bulk import csv

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

what will be the best way to load data from csv to Azure cosmos graph ( gremline ) DB?
I checked below link for.net
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-graph-dotnet

but not getting full phase for load data from csv .
Any suggestion for bulk load from csv file

Note :
I read below link for : [Azure cosmos db bulk import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60311641/azure-cosmos-db-bulk-import)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bulk import from CSV to Azure cosmos graph, you can consider using the SDK [graph BulkExecutor .NET library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-graph-dotnet). Regarding how to use the sdk, please refer to the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmosdb-graph-bulkexecutor-dotnet-getting-started)

Comment: The graph bulk executor seems to simply spawn lots of tasks to upload the gremlin elements in parallel (rather than, say, maintain one or more streams to continuously upload a large number of gremlin elements). This approach seems to quickly saturate the request limit. The Azure SDK nuget package overview doesn't even list a stable Cosmos nuget package at the time of writing: https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/releases/latest/dotnet.html